# How to Minify CSS to its Absolute Minimalistic Essence?

Tags: css, performance, whitespace, minify

Dear folks, staring at the *minified* CSS I put together so proudly the other  night, I desparately tried to remove more chars here or there, like those wasted whitespace: " " *`meanwhile the more I stared at this code, the more I started to see patterns, clearly emerging from these bodies, asif this was the absolute minimum, plus some hidden message`* Now let me get to the point for this question is already too contaminated with nonvital letters already: Is there a  way we could further minify my otherwise humungously gigantuous monster css file into a more bandwith friendly, really small file? Much appreceated!

[image]

Comment: Because removing the whitespace that is remaining could break your layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If your css is hosted on the same site as your images, use relative paths in your url()s: `background:url(/path/to/file.png)`
2. Use shorthand where applicable: `margin:0` instead of `margin:0px 0px 0px 0px`
3. Try running the CSS through a real minifier such as the [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)
4. As a last resort, shorten your class names in the CSS and the related HTML
5. Pass it to the left...

Comment: +1 Awesome @ithcy: just replaced all `:0px 0px 0px 0px` instances with `:0`  14 characters saved time 21 occuring instances:  You saved me  ± 300 chars! Thanks.

Comment: @Sam: bear in mind that gzipping reduces the effects of repeated character strings on file size to almost nothing. Obviously there’s no harm in squeezing what you can from minification, but generally you won’t get very noticeable results.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite: When You don't have control over your server environment (mod_deflate etc), a good minifier is a really useful thing.

Comment: @ithcy: sure, but whenever I've measured it, minification alone takes off about 10-15%, compared to 60-90% for gzipping. So I reckon you’d be better off spending your time getting a server environment that gzips stuff, it’s not exactly a specialist, high-end feature. You’d expect any half-decent hosting service to do it automatically, if only to reduce their own costs.

Comment: @Paul: Agreed of course, but it's not something you can count on 100% of the time. We can't always have full control over our host environments.

Comment: @ithcy: sure, but you can sign up for a different host environment. gzipping is easy and beneficial enough that its absence should be a deal-breaker for web-based endeavours unless there’s a pretty resounding reason why not. If bandwidth is important to you, you‘ll get much more from your time by using it to switch to a host environment that supports gzip, rather than removing some characters from your CSS files.

Comment: @Paul: Sure, if you're just working on your own project. But suppose you're doing a project for a client - you don't always have the option to change hosts. I'm just saying it's not always under your control. I am fully agreed with you, though.

Comment: @ithcy: ah, that’s true. If the client is concerned about performance, yet doesn’t want to make gzip happen, it might be in your interests to find another client. That sort of institutional stupidity is going to hurt you in lots of ways.

Comment: @Paul: find another host, failing that find another client, failing that find another job, failing that find another career... Got it :)

Comment: @ithcy: that’s it! I should have put that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a bunch of "`0px`" values in there, just make them "`0`" to save a couple of characters each there. Also, your negative `text-indent`s could be `-999em` instead which saves a couple of characters and equals roughly the same depending on the base `font-size`.

And as [@ithcy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344448/how-to-minify-css-to-its-absolute-minimalistic-essence/5344594#5344594) said, use short relative paths or re-host at [imgur](http://www.imgur.com/) and reference as `url(//imgur.com/name.jpg)` instead will save some bytes too.

Edit: Duh, I just re-read @ithcy's answer and it mentions most of what I said anyway.